# Postsharp update problems in common packages

Tags: asp.net, nuget, ioc-container, postsharp, continuous-deployment

We had a common project where we had exception handling. And using Postsharp sounded smart. The thing is now it is an obstacle in our daily Nuget updates.

Fixing the version number is also fishy as we want the latest versions. And we can not introduce IoC containers as they are mutually exclusive.

Any work around I am missing ?

[image: Updates fail and we need the updates]

[image: Mutually exclusive]

Comment: Out of interest, can you explain what you mean by "And we can not introduce IoC containers as they are mutually exclusive"?

Comment: We need to be able to use the interfaces to inject from the composite root. And we got a response from postsharp that can not be interfaced. https://twitter.com/postsharp/status/555276021445193728

Comment: So you build your Common project as a NuGet package? How do you specify the dependency on PostSharp in the .nuspec file? It seems that you depend on exact version instead of a range (4.0.34+).

Comment: yes. We have a ci.nuspec file. And  this is our setting   <dependencies>
<dependency id="PostSharp" version="[4.0.34]"/>

Comment: Ok, so this sets dependency on 4.0.34 exactly. Would it help if you specify dependency this way <dependencies> <dependency id="PostSharp" version="4.0.34"/> ?